# Error Given For Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a program and my compiler gets an error after the first for loop. I've been trying to fix it for a long time but it doesn't work. My compiler says that there is a std::out_of_range error. Btw I am intermediate in coding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  /* A = 4
  B = 3
  C = 2
  D = 1
  F = 0*/


  double gpa = 0;
      char grade;
  int gradeamount;

  cout << "Welcome to GPA calculator. This tells you your GPA by inputting your grades. How many grades do you have." << endl;
  cin >> gradeamount;
  cin.ignore();
  vector<char> grades;

  for(int i = 1; i <= gradeamount; i++)
  {
    cout << "What is your " << i << " grade? In Caps Please." << endl;
    cin >> grade;
    cin.ignore();
    grades.push_back(grade);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i <= (int) grades.size(); i++)
  {
    if(grades.at(i) = 'A')
      gpa += 4;

    else if(grades.at(i) = 'B')
      gpa += 3;

    else if(grades.at(i) = 'C')
      gpa += 2;

    else if(grades.at(i) = 'D')
      gpa += 1;

    else if(grades.at(i) = 'F')
      gpa +=0;

    else
    {
      cout << "That is not a grade, if it is try capitalizing it." << endl;
      int main();
    }
  }


  gpa /= (double) grades.size();

  cout << "Your GPA is: " << gpa << endl;
}
```

Comment: `int i = 0; i <= (int) grades.size();` is almost never correct - that should be just **`<`**. Move the extra `=` to here: `if(grades.at(i) = 'A')`, as that is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You have an indexing problem. In C++ arrays are zero indexed. In the first loop, it is clear you want to present a count of grates to the user beginning at 1. Instead, the foolproof method is to formulate each loop as . .

```
for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {}
```

And then in the initial loop use the following to get desired behaviour.

```
cout << "What is your " << i+1 << " grade? ...
```

The out of bounds error occurs because `grades.at(grades.size())` is past the end of the array in the second loop, which will be hit because the loop iterates over `grades.size()+1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do **recursion on main**! What are you doing, you first  accepted incorrect input, then you created whole copy of your data to do all this AGAIN from start. And after you exit main, you'll return into the same for() loop.

You have error in ifs, using = instead of ==.

Actually your grade calculator might be shorter..  if you use for() , you can use iterator or had to use < grades.size(). Otherwise you can ditch both for and your long ifs together, using lambda function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//... skipped code ... 

const std::string rates = "FDCBA";
std::for_each(grades.begin(), grades.end(), [&gpa,&rates](const char &c)
{ 
    gpa += rates.find(c); // determine index
});

//... skipped code ...
```

or use iterator:

```
for(auto it = grades.begin(); it != grades.end(); it++)
    gpa += rates.find(*it);
```

or using range for():

```
for (char c : grades)
    gpa += rates.find(c);
```

move check for proper input into the loop where you DO input, with

```
if((c>='A')&&(c<='F'))
```

or something similar. That would be the sane behavior of program